# Converting two bytes into a UIn16 in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to create a UInt16 value from two bytes in Kotlin. Here's what I came up with:

```
fun BytesToUInt16(b1 : Byte, b2 : Byte) : UInt {
  val uInt16Value = ((b1.toUShort() shl 8) or (b2.toUShort())
  return uInt16Value
}
```

But shift a UInt16 with shl seems not to be possible in Kotlin.
What is the correct way to create a UInt16 from two bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
//BytesToUInt16 
//I have two bytes 
fun bytesToUInt16(byte1: Byte, byte2: Byte): Int {
   return ((byte1.toInt() and 0xFF) shl 8) or (byte2.toInt() and 0xFF)
}

//create a byte
val byte1: Byte = 0b11111111.toByte()
val byte2: Byte = 0b11111111.toByte()
val result = bytesToUInt16(byte1, byte2)
println(result) // 65535

//// 258
val byte3: Byte = 0b00000001.toByte()
val byte4: Byte = 0b00000010.toByte()
val result2 = bytesToUInt16(byte3, byte4)
println(result2) // 258
```